# mongodb update only if the desired document is last, otherwise insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm implementing a notifications system, where I have a `notifications` collection with the following schema:

```
{
    user_id: Number,
    message: String,
    count: Number,
    timestamp: Date
}
```

Whenever there are 2 or more consecutive notifications for the same user with the same `message`, I want to prevent storing all of them. Instead, I just want to increment `count` by 1.

Here is the node.js code that handles inserting new notifications with the approach described above:

```
async function createNotification(user_id, message) {
    const notifications = db.collection('notifications');
    const [lastNotification] = await notifications.find({ user_id })
        .sort({ timestamp: -1 }).limit(1).toArray();

    if(lastNotifcation?.message === message) {
        await notifications.updateOne(
            { _id: lastNotifcation._id },
            { count: lastNotifcation.count+1 },
        )
    } else {
        await notifications.insertOne({ user_id, message, count: 1, timestamp: new Date() });
    }
}
```

While the code above works, it is not atomic (it isn't a single operation).
How can I achieve the logic above with one operation instead of two?

Comment: Have you checked out the [upsert option](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#insert-a-new-document-if-no-match-exists--upsert-)?

Comment: @ray yes. But how do you upsert IF the matching notification was last (had the largest value for timestamp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I believe wrapping your existing work in [transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/) should be the option that involves minimal change, you can opt for leveraging the aggregation pipeline for all the work.

1. `$match` to check for existing data
2. `$sort` + `$limit: 1` to get last record
3. `$set` + `$add` to increment counter
4. `$setUnion` with your default data for "insert template"
5. `$setWindowFields` to compute `$rank` for the `user_id` partition

   - `sortBy` `timestamp` to compute `rank`
   - if there is existing data from step 2, 3 it will have rank: 1, since its timestamp will be smaller than `$$NOW` current timestamp of "insert template"
   - if there is no existing data, the "insert template" will have rank: 1
6. `$match` to pick up only our `rank: 1` data and `$unset` to clean up the `rank` field
7. `$merge` to upsert back to the collection

```js
db.notifications.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      // your input user_id and message to upsert here
      "user_id": 1,
      "message": "update case - count should be incremented"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "timestamp": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "count": {
        "$add": [
          "$count",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "notifications",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$documents": [
            // document to insert if not found
            {
              "user_id": 1,
              "message": "msg to insert",
              "count": 1,
              "timestamp": "$$NOW"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$user_id",
      "sortBy": {
        "timestamp": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          "$rank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "rank": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "rank"
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "notifications",
      "on": [
        "user_id",
        "message"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground for matched / update count case](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_mGe67lg0Kq)
[Mongo Playground for unmatched / insert case](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S57UMX1nx9p)
[Mongo Playground for no record / insert case](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_a8XYMLhYMj)